# Ember-simple-Auth addon throws error

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth, typeerror

I just installed ember-simple-auth (version 1.3.0) in my application. Before insalling addon, the application is working fine but after installing it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value).on is not a function
at Module.callback (vendor.js:71693)
at Module.exports (vendor.js:123)
at Module._reify (vendor.js:157)
at Module.reify (vendor.js:144)
at Module.exports (vendor.js:121)
at requireModule (vendor.js:38)
at Class._extractDefaultExport (vendor.js:97027)
at Class.resolveOther (vendor.js:96724)
at Class.superWrapper [as resolveOther] (vendor.js:33300)
at Class.resolve (vendor.js:15968)
```

I tried to remove ember-disable-prototype-extensions from package.json of added addon as per this [Ember CLI Hook/Event Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041446/ember-cli-hook-event-error/32061515#32061515). Still didn't work.

```
"devDependencies": {
"bootstrap": "3.3.6",
"broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.2",
"ember-ajax": "0.7.1",
"ember-bootstrap": "0.7.0",
"ember-bootstrap-modal": "^3.0.0",
"ember-cli": "2.4.3",
"ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
"ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.6",
"ember-cli-chart": "2.0.6",
"ember-cli-clock": "2.1.1",
"ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
"ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.3",
"ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
"ember-cli-qunit": "^1.4.0",
"ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
"ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
"ember-cli-super-number": "^0.1.0",
"ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
"ember-data": "^2.4.2",
"ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.5",
"ember-froala": "2.2.3",
"ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
"ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
"ember-simple-auth": "1.3.0",
"ic-tabs": "0.1.3",
"loader.js": "^4.0.1"
```

}

and my config is here:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
var ENV = {
modulePrefix: 'hgnapp',
environment: environment,
baseURL: '/',
locationType: 'auto',
contentSecurityPolicy: {
   'connect-src' : "'self' http://localhost:4500"
},
EmberENV: {
  EXTEND_PROTOTYPES:{
    Date: false,
  },
  FEATURES: {
    // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
    // e.g. 'with-controller': true
  }
},

APP: {
  // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
  // when it is created
}
  };
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Can you share your package.json and environment/config.js files? I think I had an error similar to that a while ago with ember simple auth but that was several weeks ago

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. I have updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing:

```
EXTEND_PROTOTYPES:{
    Date: false,
  }
```

This worked for me.